# Need to execute a ResultSet twice in order it works

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a strange problem with `Hibernate` consisting that Hibernate gives me the error "could not extract ResultSet" when I try to execute a query against a `MySQL` database which must return a collection. The strange thing is that, when I inspect the query using the `Eclipse` display and after doing that, I continue with the normal flow, the query is executed successfully. So it seems it's neccessary to execute it twice.

The line which fails is "Collection res = query.getResultList();"

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    public Collection getByCriteria(String criteria, Collection params) {
    try {
        if (params != null) {
            Iterator itParams;
            itParams = params.iterator();
            Query query = em.createQuery(criteria).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
            //query.setHint("toplink.refresh", "true");
            for (int i = 0; itParams.hasNext(); i++) {
                query.setParameter(i + 1, itParams.next());
            }
            Collection res = query.getResultList();
            return res;
        } else {
            Query query = em.createQuery(criteria).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
            Collection res = query.getResultList();
            return res;
        }

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at es.indra.inbase.common.crudBBDD.ManagerBBDDImpl.getByCriteria(ManagerBBDDImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

(etc.)
```

Comment: Please show some code, divination is not working today.

Comment: And also post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: It's SQLGrammarException, it sounds as though your criteria String might have something to do with that. Or even better - `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />` in `persistence.xml` and showing the query created when grammar exception occurs

Comment: The "etc" part is exactly contradictory to my request to post the FULL stacktrace :/ The root cause has now already effectively been removed from it.